# Why don't variables work normally with Lit's `css` template literal function?

Tags: html, css, typescript, lit

I'm trying to abstract away my web component theme like this:

```js
import { css } from 'lit';

const theme = {
  primary: '#fff'
}

export const baseCss = css`
  :host {
    --primary: ${theme.primary}
  }
`
```

However, at least in TypeScript, this doesn't work, and here's the error message I get:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | CSSResultGroup'.
```

Why would Lit expose a template tag literal function only for it to not be able to receive variable interpolation?

Is it because of code injection? Because `unsafeCSS` does seem to work.

Comment: [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Using the [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wjDz7m) does not work... I know it should since I have used lit before. Do you have a minimal repro of the issue?

Comment: Even more minimal than this???

Comment: Take a moment to read https://lit.dev/docs/components/styles/  and you would have your answer - by default direct strings are disallowed for security. You can do`css\`#fff\``  at source or `unsafeCSS(theme.primary)` at target if you don't have to worry about where the CSS comes from.